# Adding devices to team provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I need to add a device to my team provisioning profile, however I do not physically have the device so I can't hook it up to my computer so Xcode can't add the UDID to my devices and to the team provisioning profile.  Is there a way to add it manually to the team provisioning profile, I can't figure out how to edit it.  Also when I add the device in my provisioning portal it doesn't get added to my team provisioning profile automatically.

Comment: Something does occasionally seem to cause the Team Profile to update with your entire device list.  I think it's when you add a new device through Xcode, although I can't be sure.  However if you create a profile you manage yourself and turn on "Automatic Device Provisioning" in the Organizer, the "Refresh" button will automatically download a new copy of your custom profile whenever after you make a change.

Comment: The Refresh button in XCode worked for me on the Team Provisioning Profile. Thanks, useful tip!

Comment: Refresh button worked for me too and it loaded all devices.

Answer (score 142):

This worked for me:

1. Login to your iPhone provisioning portal through https://developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in devices
3. Go back to Xcode, open up the Organizer and select "Provisioning Profiles", ensure that "Automatic Device Provisioning"  is checked on the top right pane, then click on the "Refresh" button, and magically all your devices set in the provisioning portal will be automatically added.

Comment: The Automatic Device Provisioning checkbox was removed in Xcode 4.5

Comment: It was removed, but does that mean it is turned on by default and always?

Comment: In later versions of Xcode - tested on Xcode 6 - "Automatic Device Provisioning" is **on** by default. So add your device through the portal and hit refresh - your device is now auto-magically attached to your provisioning profile.

Comment: @thattyson what do you mean by "hit refresh" where? And where is "Automatic Device Provisioning" located to see where it is *on*

Comment: @Deminetix Go to Xcode > Preferences > "Accounts" tab > Select your Apple ID (left pane) > Double click on your Team Name. Click "Download All" to refresh your provisioning profiles. Automatic device provisioning isn't as easy turning it on/off but you can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Comment: @thattyson : do I need to enroll for apple developer program if I want to get access to provisioning profile??

Comment: Anyone know how to 'refresh' in Xcode 9? They removed the Download All option referred to above.

Comment: @JasonH See my latest answer for you.

Answer (score 17):

right click on the device, then select 'add device to provisioning profile'

Answer (score 15):

For Xcode 6 it is a little different.

After adding the device UDID in the developer site (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action), go back to Xcode.

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts
Select the Apple ID you added the device under and in the bottom right, click "View Details..."

Hit the refresh icon on the bottom left and then try to run the app again.

Comment: The refresh icon isn't there anymore

Comment: This is correct except it changed to: Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts Select the Apple ID -> Download Manual Profiles

Answer (score 14):

Per May 16th 2013, using XCode 4.6.2, I had to do the following to add a device (which I do not have physical access to) to the team provisioning profile:

1. Login to the provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in Devices
3. Select the Team Provisioning profile in Provisioning Profiles
4. Click the Edit button
5. And under devices for that provisioning profile, click Select All, or just the devices you want included.
6. Click Generate
7. Then go back to XCode and click refresh icon (bottom right) under Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles

Sometimes it takes a while before the certificate is updated and fetched from XCode.

Hope this helps new readers.

Comment: No more Provisioning Profiles tab in Organiser in XCode 5. I guess that means it's all automatic now?

Comment: In xCode 5, it's moved to Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details (under the apple ID) -> then hit the tiny refresh button at the bottom. My guess is, it was too easy to do in xCode 4, so apple moved it somewhere harder to find

Comment: If the Provisioning Profile is `"Managed By Xcode"` the "Edit" button is greyed out on the website.

Comment: Since we've got XCode 5 now, a lot has changed, but clicking delete will make XCode create a new one for you. And I think all devices will be automatically added for you.

Answer (score 12):

I faced multiple time the same issue that I add device info to portal so I can publish build to fabric testing but device is still missing due to how Xcode is not updating team provisioning profile.

So based on other answers and my own experience, the best and quickest way is to remove all Provisioning profiles manually by command line while automatic signing will download them again with updated devices.

If this can lead to some unknown issues I don't know and highly doubt, but it works for me just fine.

So just:

```
cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
rm *
```

And try again...

Comment: Maybe a few explanations would be useful?

Comment: @olinox14 now its too much text I think haha

Comment: `cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` if you already had the terminal open in another directory, cd Library/.. would fail, and rm could potentially be bad

Comment: I don't claim to understand any of this magic... but what i can say is that removing all the existing profiles worked.

Answer (score 11):

Workaround for adding a device to an existing (automatically or manually created) provisioning profile (tested in Xcode 8.2.1):

1. Add the device in the developer portal.
2. Only when using a manually created profile: add the device to the profile.
3. In Xcode, go to Xcode > Preferences > "Accounts" tab > select your Apple ID (left pane) > double click on your Team Name.
4. Locate the existing provisioning profile. (automatically created profiles will begin with 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile' or 'XC iOS' or similar.
5. Right click on the profile.
6. Choose 'Move to Trash'.
7. The profile will disappear. A new profile with the same name might appear again, that is OK.

Xcode should now be aware of the newly added device.

Comment: Wau impressive how apple don't like its developers

Comment: I added a new device in the portal and headed back to XCode and created a .ipa, it worked and I have no idea how/why? XCode 7.3

Answer (score 9):

Get the UDID from iTunes:
http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

Once you have that:

1. Login to your iphone provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in devices.
3. Add the device to the provisioning profile.
4. Download the profile again and enjoy.

Comment: The portal won't let you add devices to the Team Provisioning portal as it is managed by Xcode, so that won't work for me.

Comment: Create your own provisioning profile. The team provisioning profile isn't the only profile you're allowed to have.

Comment: Everyone is added to the team provisioning profile automatically. All you have to do is add the device and then refresh in Xcode.

Comment: +1, this is the key bit of information in this thread if you don't want to involve Xcode.

Comment: And what do you do when it isn't added to the provisioning profile automatically?

Comment: On step 4, after you download the updated profile, double click on it to install on your dev machine (instead of moving it manually...)

Comment: do I need to enroll for apple developer program if I want to get access to provisioning profile? I am trying an ad-hoc distribution

Comment: To comment on what the link reveals - you can get your UDID by clicking on the label "Serial Number" in iTunes, which magically changes it to UDID/other device details. This sort of magic-clicking UI behavior is strange to me.

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of provisioning profiles.

- development and
- distribution

When app is live on app store then distribution profiles works and do not need any devices to be added.

Only development profiles need to add devices.In order to do so these are the steps-

1. Login to developer.apple.com member centre.
2. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
3. Get UDID of your device and add it in the devices.
4. Select a developer provisioning profile and edit it.
5. Click on check box next to the device you just added.
6. Generate and download the profile.
7. Double click on it to install it.
8. Connect your device and retry.

This worked for me hope it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

- Login to your iPhone provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
- Add the UDID in devices
- Go to Provisioning Profile sections. Click on your provisioning profile, click on Edit.
- In Device section select your added device and generate provisioning certificate again.
- Download it and double click. It will automatically added in your Xcode.
- To check UDID present in .ipa file or not. Generate .ipa file and upload on diawi.com, get diawi link and hit on Safari browser. You can check their how many UDID are integrated in generated .ipa.

Answer (score 3):

Note that testers are no longer added via UUID in the new Apple TestFlight.

Test Flight builds now require an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile. The portal does not allow UUIDs to be added to this type of provisioning profile.

Instead, add "Internal Testers" via iTunes Connect:

> Internal testers are iTunes Connect users with the Admin or Technical role. They can be added in Users and Roles.

After adding a user, be sure to click on their name and flip the "Internal Tester" switch.

[image: Internal Tester Toggle Switch]

Then, go to `App > Prerelease > Internal Testers` and invite them to the build.

Answer (score 2):

After you've added the UDID to the devices in Provisioning Portal manually, you should trick Xcode into generating a new Team Provisioning Profile (with the newly added device included). Follow these steps:

1. Open Organizer > Devices > Library > Provisioning Profiles. Find the existing (old) profile (that does not include the newly added device). Delete it.
2. Connect one of your own devices. Right-click on it in Organizer > Devices > Devices. Choose 'Add Device to Provisioning Portal'.

This will trick Xcode into generating a new Team Provisioning Profile, which automatically includes devices you've added in Provisioning Portal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently created new provisioning profiles, you will have to disconnect your phone, close XCode.  Then open XCode, refresh your accounts then build and deploy at least once to your phone.

Answer (score 2):

After adding UDID in developer.apple.com, do the following steps:

1, Go to Xcode, open Preferences (cmd + ,) -> Accounts -> Click your Apple ID -> View Details
[image]

2, In the new window, click on "Refresh", then "Request"
[image]

3, Now try to run your app on the new device, if you get an error saying "unfound provisioning profile", keep reading

4, Click on your project
[image]

6, Find "Fix It" button in Identity section, click it
[image]

7, Now try to run again, it should work

Answer (score 2):

Update for Xcode (Version 9.1). Please follow below steps for refreshing Provisioning profiles

Using Xcode Organizer

- Select Export

[image]

- Select desired distribution facility

[image]

- Now Select Automatically Manage Signing Identity
  [image]
- In next Screen Please click on **Profile** tag detail discloser button which will navigate you to Provisioning profile Folder

[image]

- Select all profiles and trash them. Now in Xcode click on the Previous button and click again on Automatically Manage Signing, Now Xcode will create new signing identity for you with latest features (including new device id's)

> In short, you can navigate to MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ folder path and delete all profiles and then Archive. Now you can see there are new profiles for you. Cheers :)

@JasonH hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

As of Sept 2018, Apple seems to (or a bug) block the normal way to get your XS and XS Max's UDID. Even XCode could not properly register new phones for you.

After a couple hours of digging, I figure it out:

- Connect your iPhone to your Mac.
- Navigate to  -> About This Mac.
- Click on System Report and select USB.
- Click on iPhone, and copy the value next to the Serial Number label.
- Copy and paste the value. **You then need to add a – after the 8th digit.**
- This is the UDID for the iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max.

[Source](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2018/09/how-find-iphone-xs-max-udid.html)

Answer (score 2):

Now for Xcode 12.5
You need to create a new Apple Distribution Certificates

1. Go to Xcode Preference
2. Click Account, choose your Team you want to update
3. Click Manage Certificates
4. Click + Apple Distribution Certificates
5. Go to Keychain and delete the old certificate

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in XCode 7.3

1. Login to developer.apple.com
2. Add the device.
3. Head straight back to XCode **(DO NOTHING)** and create the .ipa
4. Install the build on the device, it will work.

I have no idea how this worked since I didn't download a new provisioning profile which included the newly added device, neither did I touch anything in XCode after adding the new device. That's Apple magic for you.

I will try to add an explanation to this if I find one.

Comment: This worked for me too in Xcode 11 - UDID was added automatically through AppCenter, but for the rest the doing nothing part was all that was needed. Archived and exported the app again, new device was added.

Answer (score 0):

login to developer account of apple and open the provision profile that you have selected in settings and add the device . The device will automatically displayed if connected to PC.

Answer (score 0):

All answers I've seen above assumed that the developer owns an iPhone. No one knows the right answer. As far as I know, you need:

- a physical iPhone that you own
- or UDID of someone else's iPhone.
  But it is a must to have an iPhone before you publish your app. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't answer the question :-)

Answer (score -2):

Xcode 10.3

In finder navigate to: MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
and delete all files there.

Then Archive and Automatically manage singing.

You are done!