# Organiser wont install profile to device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, installation

Have an error when trying to build to a device saying a valid profile is not available so decided to make a fresh one but, device will not install it through Organiser - I can click 'add profiles' and have it on desktop, can select it but then nothing changes when goes back to organiser. Have profiles showing under 'profiles' but just won't add to device itself. Have also dragged to install into XCode as normal and comes up in target and build settings.

Any thoughts on whats happening? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

In order to install a provisioning profile to a device, the device should be added to the provisioning profile. Check out this [**Adding devices to team provisioning profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile), SO post.

Comment: Hi EmptyStack, thanks for helping - just read through and have already tried the refresh - in the provisioning list on the organiser it actually has the profile I made and in the bottom section it states it is linked to work with my device - problem is that on the device's screen that same profile won't show up?  Sorry