# Question about Developer Certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, release, iphone-developer-program

I have a developer certificate; 
I want to compile my project with a release version.
How many device can I use to try my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your app in maximum of 100 devices provided that those devices UUID's are added to the developer provisioning profile. Check out this [**Adding devices to team provisioning profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile), SO post for reference.

Comment: you can add up to 100 devices to your profile. when your account renews after a year you can delete devices you don't want anymore once.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many devices added to a certificate and as many simulators(computers) using the same certificate to install apps on multiple devices.