# I can not install ipa on my device

Tags: ios7, iphone-5, ipa

I do not understand because if I have my device udid iphone 5 with ios 7.0.4, it fails to install the ipa, but other devices that works for me ... I need help

Comment: How do you install your .ipa?

Comment: with diawi.com or itunes ,
I only fault with that udid, it can be a thing of the device?

Comment: And with XCode? Utilitary of Configuration iPhone?

Comment: Ipa xcode5 use and distribution with the correct profile, the other devices suits me just this particular failure for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your device identifier isn't included in provision profile. You can add it in member center. 
This can help you: [Adding devices to team provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile)

Comment: whether, if that is included, if I go to edit the profile I get all devices on the account, it is true that once I went gray as disabled but I went back to put in enabled and I added again, so I do not understand that happens to me with just udid