# How to publishing to .IPA from VS for Mac

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I wanna Publishing .IPA,This step is success,but I cant install in my Iphone via Xcode,that show :

[image]

BTW, I can use Xcode with Swift publish .IPA ,and success install it,
but I'm must use Xamarin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For publishing your application on App store, you need to sign the application using distribution provisioning profile and certificate. By using distribution provisioning profile you can't install your application on device.

If you need to install your application on device please use the development provisioning profile and certificate to sign the application.

For further reference please visit -

[XCode 8 A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290033/xcode-8-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found)

Comment: yes,Im checked I use Developer Certificate,but still not.

Comment: In that case, either your device is not added in to the developer provisioning profile OR it's not added/registered in developer account and if it's already added in account, than it may be not added in provisioning profile. 

For further reference please  go through the below url


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile