# How to Deploy xamarin.forms app to iOS Device?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.ios

I follow all steps but i can't see my account on visual studio. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows )

I use visual studio 2017 professional and My apple account is free

Steps:

1.Make sure that Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2017 has been paired to a Mac build host. (check)

2.Connect your iOS device to the Mac build host via USB or wirelessly. (check)

3.In the Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer, right-click on your Xamarin.iOS project and select Properties. (check)

4.Navigate to iOS Bundle Signing. (check)

5.For Configuration, select Debug. (check)

6.For Platform, select iPhone. (check)

7.Select Manual Provisioning. (check)

8.Select the Signing Identity created by Xcode. (Doesn't listed)

9.Select the Provisioning Profile created by Xcode. (Doesn't listed)

Comment: Have you added the Apple Account in your visual-studio?

Comment: You have to install Signing Certificate.

Comment: Before trying this on the Windows side, I would recommend creating a small project in XCode and then to try to deploy it

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i couldn't because when i try add account to visual studio. response error message is: "There was an error while trying to log in: A server with the specified hostname could not be found"

Comment: @MouseOnMars it is ok from mac side

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio 2017? You can also have a try with VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Login to the provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
2)Add the UDID in Devices
3)Select the Team Provisioning profile in Provisioning Profiles
4)Click the Edit button And under devices for that provisioning profile, click Select All or just the devices you want to be included.

For more information refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578158/adding-devices-to-team-provisioning-profile
```